# Permissions in Node JS

Tags: node.js, security, express, permissions, sequelize.js

I'm making an app using express and sequelize. There are users and admins. Right now, I'm dealing with permissions through middleware.

Say there's a message that users can change:

```
var Message = sequelize.define('Message', {
    content: Sequelize.STRING,
    secret: Sequelize.STRING
});

var message = Message.build({
    content: 'i like frogs',
    secret: 'i like hogs more!'
});

app.put('/message', requireRole('user'), function(request, response) {
    message.updateAttributes(request.body.content);
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end('secret updated');
});
```

I would like to have some more complex permissions.

What is a good way of going about this? In this example, I would want users to be able to update the message's `content`, but not its `secret`.

I could bake it into each route, but it seems that it would be a pain to modify as models change.

```
app.put('/message', requireRole('user'), function(request, response) {
    var attrs = {};
    var role = request.session.user.role;
    if (role == 'user' || role == 'admin') {
        attrs.content = request.body.content;
    }
    if (role == 'admin') {
        attrs.secret = request.body.secret;
    }
    message.updateAttributes(attrs);
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end('secret updated');
});
```

Are there better ways of doing this? I was thinking I could put this logic into Sequelize's get / set methods for defined models, for instance, but don't know if that's any cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

To my mind this is bad idea to put such a logic into model at all. Especially into setters of the model, since this conflicts with two [OOP SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) (Single responsibility principle and Interface segregation principle).

In general there is a pattern named ACL (access control list) where you define which **roles** can do any **actions** over some **resources**. This one for example: https://www.npmjs.org/package/acl

When you inject ACL into your project this:

```
  if (role == 'user' || role == 'admin') {
      attrs.content = request.body.content;
  }
  if (role == 'admin') {
      attrs.secret = request.body.secret;
  }
```

Will be replaced by something like this:

```
request.body.forEach(
  field => {
    ACL.isAllowed(
      request.session.user.role,
      field,
      'edit',
      ( error, response ) => {
        if( response ){
          attrs[ field ] = request.body[ field ]; /** validate me!  */
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

);

As I see from your example, provided npm package should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is quite old but in case if somebody will face the same question, there is an [article which explain how to integrate ACL](https://medium.com/netscape/authorization-with-casl-in-express-app-d94eb2e2b73b) in express based app

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Passport](http://passportjs.org/), it's quite simple to use and allows you to implement local auth and OpenID for seconds.

Comment: Passport helps you with _authentication_ not _access control_